# Match each value of a column of a data frame with the value of a column of another data frame (if the latter exists)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame `df` structured as follows (I report only one column, the others are not relevant):

```
CDS_COD
-------
A001
D015
B006
C002
D015
X099
```

Also I have another data frame `df1`  structured as follows:

```
Cod cds | School
------- | ------
A001    | 0
A001    | Math
B006    | Science
B006    | Science
C002    | History
D015    | 0
```

My goal is to find a correspondence between the codes `CDS_COD` of the data frame `df` and the schools `School` of the dataframe `df1` (if the respective code `Cod cds` exists and does not match 0, in the other cases I will report that I have not found a match). In summary, my output in this case should be:

```
CDS_COD | School
------- | ------
A001    | Math
D015    | N/A
B006    | Science
C002    | History
D015    | N/A
X099    | N/A
```

I know how to do this and the code is

```
df = pd.read_excel('...')
df1 = pd.read_excel('...')

codes = np.array(df['CDS_COD'].tolist())

schools = np.array([None] * len(codes))

for i in range(len(schools)):
    df2 = df1[df1['Cod cds'] == codes[i]]
    if len(df2) > 0:
        df3 = df2[df2['School'] != 0]
        if len(df3) > 0:
            schools[i] = df3['School'].iloc[0]
        else:
            schools[i] = 'N/A'
    else:
        schools[i] = 'N/A'
```

but obviously it is inefficient.

Does anyone know in ways to make it more efficient and maybe even more elegant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to do a left join.

You need to clean a bit your second dataframe first to remove rows with School = 0 and duplicates.

```
df1.merge(df2.query('School != "0"').drop_duplicates(),
          left_on='CDS_COD',
          right_on='Cod cds',
          how='left'
         ).drop('Cod cds', axis=1)
```

output:

```
  CDS_COD   School
0    A001     Math
1    D015      NaN
2    B006  Science
3    C002  History
4    D015      NaN
5    X099      NaN
```

input:

```
>>> df1
  CDS_COD
0    A001
1    D015
2    B006
3    C002
4    D015
5    X099

>>> df2
  Cod cds   School
0    A001        0
1    A001     Math
2    B006  Science
3    B006  Science
4    C002  History
5    D015        0
```

Comment: I think it is `df` instead of `df1` and `df1` instead of `df2`. Aside from this typo it works. Is there a way to replace `NaN` with `N/A` directly in that line of code?

Comment: Add `.fillna('N/A')` at the very end. And yes I used df1/df2 instead of df/df1.